# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query with sub query

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which I am inserting value which is average of price in another table.
I am using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  query but the problem is i am updating value from sub query and it is returning error that column can not be null.

```
insert into `averge_figures` (`full_postcode`,`property_type`,`bedrooms`,`rental_figure`)
    select p.full_postcode,p.property_type,p.bedrooms,

    ((select avg(p2.price) as price1 from property p2  where p.full_postcode=p2.full_postcode and p.bedrooms=p2.bedrooms
      and p.property_type=p2.property_type and p2.trans_type_id=2 )+
     (select avg(s.price) as price2 from sale_detail s where s.proptype=p.property_type and s.bedrooms=p.bedrooms 
     and s.postcode=p.full_postcode and s.rentorsale='R'))/2 

   from property p 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `rental_figure`=

 ((select avg(p2.price) as price1 from property p2  where p.full_postcode=p2.full_postcode and p.bedrooms=p2.bedrooms
  and p.property_type=p2.property_type and p2.trans_type_id=2 )+
 (select avg(s.price) as price2 from sale_detail s where s.proptype=p.property_type and s.bedrooms=p.bedrooms 
 and s.postcode=p.full_postcode and s.rentorsale='R'))/2
```

can any body correct my mysql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `rental_figure` = VALUES(`rental_figure`)
```

`VALUES()` returns the value which would of been inserted if there was no duplicate.

Comment: This is a great tip, and came in useful for me. It should probably be accepted as the answer.